# How to fetch the first element in a collection in java

Tags: java, collections, hashset, linkedhashset

My question is, How to fetch the first element in a collection in java

Example :

```
LinkedHashSet h1 = new LinkedHashSet();   
h1.add("Ani","Broadway NY",10001);
```

And I want to fetch "Ani"   only

How can I do this?

Comment: h1.iterator().next()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Iterator iterator = h1.iterator();
if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String firstElement = iterator.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A safe approach would be to stream it and use `findFirst()`:

```
Object first = h1.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the simplest way to get first element in a java collection:

```
first = collection.iterator().next();
```